# regex: conditional regex with backreference and keep the group names in Python?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I need to match the following two strings:

### 1.

```
string1 = "the following paired punc can be, and also can be nothing, [ if the last one is ]"  # otherwise it should not match.
```

### 2.

```
string2 = "the following paired punc can be, and also can be nothing, { if the last one is }"  # otherwise it should also not match.
```

The expected outputs correspondingly:

```
if matched:
    try:
        assert(matched.group("lastpunc1") == "]")
        print("punc1 matched")
        assert(matched.group("lastpunc2") == "}")
        print("punc2 matched")
    except:
        pass
```

The two groups should be named for later use.
I learned that checking if a Capture Group at a Relative Position has been set is not supported by Python from [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html#check_namedgroup).

I have tried:

```
(?:[\w\s,])+((?(lastpunc1)\[)|(?(lastpunc2)\{))(?:[\w\s,])+(?P<lastpunc1>\])?(?P<lastpunc2>\})?$
```

The error shows that `Invalid regular expression: unknown group name`. The group named after the reference cannot be used.

Absolutely it doesn't work.

And I want to try in another direction, thus I wrote this:

```
(?:[\w,\s])+((?P<lsb>\[)|(?P<lcb>\{))?(?:[\w,\s])+((?(lsb)\]|(?‌​(lcb)\}|(?!)))|((?P<‌​rsb>\})|(?P<rcb>\]))‌​)$
```

Comment: Regex101 has some comments about that: https://regex101.com/r/g89kAy/1

Comment: You forgot to escape `[`..see **[here](https://regex101.com/r/M2jGE0/1)**..besides what you want to achieve is not at all clear. provide some examples

Comment: @rock321987 You are right but it is not the essential problem here. I have updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a simpler [`.*?(\[[^]]*]|{[^}]*})`](https://regex101.com/r/HZJ7q3/1)?

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you want. Do the 1. and 2. describe the properties of the match or is it the full text to match or what??? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pattern, you swapped the group match check and named capturing groups.

**It is not possible to reference a capture group *before* it matches in Python `re`.**, see the [reference you shared](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html#check_namedgroup):

> In PCRE (**but not** .NET, Perl, **Python** and Ruby), you can check whether a capture group at a relative position has been set. The relative position can be to the left of to the right of the conditional.

You should 1) match and capture either `[` or `{`, 2) match the optional text with `.*?` up to the first `}` or `]` depending on what was matched before, 3) *capture* into another group the trailing delimiters.

```
[\w,\s]+(?:(?P<lsb>\[)|(?P<lcb>\{))[\w,\s]+(?:(?(lsb)(?P<rsb>\])|(?(lcb)(?P<rcb>\})|(?!))))$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E4bNwL/3)

Now, you can assert if the `rsb` and `rcb` group values are correct.

Comment: Update it again to show the expected outputs for 3 scenarios (2 when matched and 1 no match).

Comment: I wrote a snippet for explanation only.

Comment: That does not make sense for now, you might as well check with `assert(matched.group("lastpunc1") == "[")`. What is your *final* goal? Do not post XY problems.

Comment: I didn't get your meaning. Sorry. The assertion syntax works. I have checked.

Comment: Compare with `[` and `{`, not with `]` and `}`.

Comment: That's exactly my point. Because "[" and "{" are not sure to appear in the string then I need "]" and "}" to check the type of the string.

Comment: If `{` and `]` are missing, acc. to your own requirements, there should be *no match*. If there is no match, you cannot "check the type of the string", as you do not have the data to compare. Please re-consider what you are doing. Most probably, you need to do this in 2 steps: 1) check if a string contains `]` or `}` at all with `if "]" in string or "}" in string`, and 2) then run the regex check.

Comment: OK. Thanks all the same.

Comment: I wrote another one: `"(?:\w|,|\s)+(?P<lsb>\[)(?P<lcb>\{)(?:\w|,|\s)+((?(lsb)\]|(?(lcb)\}|(?!)))|((?P<rsb>\})|(?P<rcb>\])))$"`. It also doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions for such kind of solutions? `lsb` stands for left square bucket.

Comment: You are making the same mistake as in the original regex: you match a sequence of `[` and `{` with `(?P<lsb>\[)(?P<lcb>\{)`, while you want to match either  one or the other, use `(?:(?P<lsb>\[)|(?P<lcb>\{))`. The `(?:\w|,|\s)+` is a very bad pattern, there are character classes for this purpose - `[\w,\s]+`. At the end, it must be `(?:(?(lsb)(?P<rsb>\])|(?‌​(lcb)(?P<rcb>\})|(?!)))`.